# How to hide Python code in Linux debian via user permission?

Tags: linux, debian, user-permissions

I'm admin of Linux machine (Debian).
I want use that machine in production with python source code inside but I don't want show it to user.
Does exist some way in order to user can only execute code and can not read it or save it on external device it?

Could be enough for example some grant permission on user created ad hoc for run code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem here is that python is an interpreted language ... that means that the user must be allowed to READ the file for the python interpreter to execute it.  You could work around that by using a python compiler.

Comment: You can try this: https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/obfuscate.html

Comment: For example autorun it at boot like root and after give permission to user only for run it, Is it possible?